# How to dispose NumericSpinner on press in CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

My Codename One app displays a `NumericSpinner` so that a user can select a number. However I can't find a way to dispose it when the user press on the center part of the "wheel". I tried to `addPointerReleasedListener` and `addPointerPressedListener` but they are never triggered neither in the simulator nor on the Android device.

Is it possible to dispose the `NumericSpinner` when the user selects (presses and releases) the center part of the spinner ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's impossible. The picker is implemented natively and we have very limited control over it. The only way to implement a feature like this would be thru native code.